# NullPointerException when accessing val field in Scala class constructor

Tags: swing, scala

I want to translate something like the following Java code into Scala:

```
private HashMap<KeyStroke,Action>actionMap=new HashMap<KeyStroke,Action>();

KeyStroke left = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0);
//....
actionMap.put(left, new AbstractAction("move left") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

My initial attempt was this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent
import java.awt.event.ActionListener
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent
import java.awt._
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.JPanel
import javax.swing.Action
import javax.swing.AbstractAction
import javax.swing.KeyStroke
import collection.mutable.HashMap
object Main{
  def main(args:Array[String]){
    val gui:GUI = new GUI()
  }
}

class GUI extends JFrame{
  initKeyboard
  pack
  this.setVisible(true)
  private val actionMap = new HashMap[KeyStroke,Action]
  def initKeyboard{
    val left = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,0)
    actionMap.put(left, new AbstractAction("Move Left"){
      override def actionPerformed(e:ActionEvent){
        println("Do something")
      }
    })//actionMap.put
  }

}
```

Note that I have not yet written code to do anything with the actionMap.

However I get the following error at runtime:

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GUI.initKeyboard(Game.scala:24)
    at GUI.<init>(Game.scala:18)
    at Main$.main(Game.scala:13)
    at Main.main(Game.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

(note that line 24 is the  line that starts "actionMap.put")

How should this be implemented?

Comment: Please provide a self standing, reproducible example.

Comment: As it stands your code is not executable (we do not know how `GUI` looks), therefore nobody can see what you are doing wrong. Just executing those three lines works fine.

Comment: please see my recent edit ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the initialization order.

The following is executed on new `GUI` instance creation, in *the order listed*:

```
initKeyboard
pack
this.setVisible(true)
private val actionMap = new HashMap[KeyStroke,Action]
```

You can see that you call `initKeyboard` *before* you initialize `actionMap`. Therefore accessing it inside `initKeyboard` throws an exception.

You can verify the initialization order with this simple example:

```
class GUI extends {
  initKeyboard
  private val actionMap = println("actionMap")
  def initKeyboard: Unit = {
    println("initKeyboard")
  }
}
new GUI // prints: initKeyboard actionMap
```